# Isolate section of long character string in R

Tags: string, r, text, character, data-manipulation

I have locality information in a vector that contains [lat.];[long.];[town name];[governorate name];[country name].

I want to create a new vector that includes just the town name for each observation.

Below you can see the contents of the vector for the first four observations.

`[1] 36.7416894818782;10.227453200912464;Ben Arous;Gouvernorat de Ben Arous;TN;
[2] 37.17652020713887;9.784534661865223;Tinjah;Gouvernorat de Bizerte;TN;

[3] 34.7313;10.763400000000047;Sfax;Sfax;TN;

[4] 34.829474860751915;9.791573033378995;Regueb;Gouvernorat de Sidi Bouzid;TN;`

I want to output a vector that looks like:

`[1] Ben Arous

[2] Tinjah

[3] Sfax

[4] Regueb`

Comment: I don't know how you imported the data, but you should probably have used `read.table` with `sep=";"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `read.table` with `sep=";"`:

```
d <- read.table(textConnection("
36.7416894818782;10.227453200912464;Ben Arous;Gouvernorat de Ben Arous;TN;
37.17652020713887;9.784534661865223;Tinjah;Gouvernorat de Bizerte;TN;
34.7313;10.763400000000047;Sfax;Sfax;TN;
34.829474860751915;9.791573033378995;Regueb;Gouvernorat de Sidi Bouzid;TN;"), 
sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

d[, 3]
# [1] "Ben Arous" "Tinjah"    "Sfax"      "Regueb"
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting a quirky response. This works except the read.table command that `line 258 did not have 6 elements`. I know that `read.table` function will not work unless every data line has the same number of values.  But when I look at line 258, I do not see any problem! Any ideas? Here's line 258: `[258] "36.8223169662737;10.30797311553954;La Goulette;Gouvernorat de Tunis;TN;"`  It looks just the same as every other line to me: five semi-colons defining six elements, where the last element is empty.

Comment: @DTRM: Your line 258 looks good. Maybe the problem is +/-1 line above/below. Maybe you want to try the argument `fill=TRUE` for `read.table`.